# Css animation In/out

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, css-animations

I'm trying to recreate the dropdown animation of the "new" google developers webpage (you can see here just click over the input search:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/app)

I can create the "in" animation and the dropdown goes down. But i'm not able to create the "out" animation and make go up the dropdown like in the Google Developers page. Here's a jsfiddle i created:

http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/53/

I poste some code btw:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="uk-width-1-1" ng-controller="TestCtrl">        
      <form id="form" class="uk-form uk-width-1-1 center-form">

              <!-- This is a button -->
              <input id="input" data-ng-click="openSearch()" hide-search="hideSearchContainer()" type="text" placeholder="text" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-vertical-align-middle">

                  <div hide-search="hideSearchContainer()" data-ng-class="{'search-results':userSearch, 'search-results-closed':!userSearch}" class="search-results-closed scrollable-vertical">
                      Hello i'm a dropdown!
                  </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

A very simple angularjs

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.openSearch = function(){
            $scope.userSearch = true;
        };
        $scope.hideSearchContainer = function(){
            $scope.userSearch = false;
        };

});

myApp.directive('hideSearch', function($document){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $document.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(attr.hideSearch);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add transition to `.search-results-closed` too:

```
.search-results-closed {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s, visibility 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/8y48q/54/

Comment: mmh, ok seems perfect but there is a little problem.. When the div disapperas seems that not disappears at all. If you check using firebug the form container has the height of the input + the div even if disappears. In this case, if i have for example a button under the input it doesn't working. Understand what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with css animations and `:focus` states.

```css
p{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: hide 1s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: hide 1s ease forwards;
}
input:focus + p{
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: show 1s ease forwards;
  animation: show 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes show{
  0%{
    height: 0px;
  }
  100%{
    height: 50px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hide{
  0%{
    height: 50px;
  }
  100%{
    height: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes show{
  0%{
    height: 0px;
  }
  100%{
    height: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes hide{
  0%{
    height: 50px;
  }
  100%{
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box" placeholder="text">
<p>Hello, I'm an alert</p>
```

Comment: I didn't add the prefixes to leave the code small, but let me fix that.

Comment: @End.Game can you see it now?